# second column isn't showing

Tags: php, html

I have a piece of code with which I pull data from my database and show that data on the page, divided in two columns. the first column shows, but the second doesn't show up... the code is as follows:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT InfoID, Titel, Inhoud FROM Informatie WHERE Pagina = "Behandelingen";');
$stmt -> execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($count == 1) {
echo '<div class="col-sm-10"><div class="panel panel-default">';
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $titel = $row['Titel'];
    $inhoud = $row['Inhoud'];
    echo "<div class='panel-heading'><b>$titel</b></div>";
    echo "<div class='panel-body'>$inhoud</div>";
}
} else if($count >= 2) {
echo '<div class="col-sm-5">';
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $titel = $row['Titel'];
    $inhoud = $row['Inhoud'];
    $infoID = $row['InfoID'];
    if ($infoID % 2 != 0) {
    echo "<div class='panel panel-default'>";
    echo "<div class='panel-heading'><b>$titel</b></div>";
    echo "<div class='panel-body'>$inhoud</div></div>";
}}
echo "</div><div class='col-sm-5'>";
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $titel = $row['Titel'];
    $inhoud = $row['Inhoud'];
    $infoID = $row['InfoID'];
    if ($infoID % 2 == 0) {
    echo "<div class='panel panel-default'>";
    echo "<div class='panel-heading'><b>$titel</b></div>";
    echo "<div class='panel-body'>$inhoud</div></div>";
}}
echo"</div>";
}
```

if anyone wants to see for himself what I mean you can see the page in question [here](http://joeymariah.me/fnb/?page=schoonheidsbehandelingen)

Comment: Include the generated HTML in your question.

Comment: Ack.  Do the "while" outside all of your "if" conditions.  And what do you mean by "second column" - I suspect you mean the second GROUP (the code within the `if ($count >=2)`.  Because you are not incrementing `$count` anywhere....

Comment: how do you mean I'm not incrementing `$count` anywhere? it's at the top right under the statement. And why the `while` statements outside the `if` statements? that would completely go against the whole reason the `if` statements are there. A column is a piece inside a `div` tag with the class `col-sm-(number)`.

Comment: @PatrickQ I know, if `rowCount()` returns 1, it makes a single column with the data of that row inside, while when it returns 2 or higher it makes two columns in which the data is placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `while ($row = $stmt->fetch())` will loop through all the results and there will be nothing to fetch in the second while statement

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT InfoID, Titel, Inhoud FROM Informatie WHERE Pagina = "Behandelingen";');
$stmt -> execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($count == 1) {
    echo '<div class="col-sm-10"><div class="panel panel-default">';
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $titel = $row['Titel'];
        $inhoud = $row['Inhoud'];
        echo "<div class='panel-heading'><b>$titel</b></div>";
        echo "<div class='panel-body'>$inhoud</div>";
    }
} 
else if($count >= 2) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo '<div class="col-sm-5">';
        $titel = $row['Titel'];
        $inhoud = $row['Inhoud'];
        $infoID = $row['InfoID'];
        if ($infoID % 2 != 0) {
            echo "<div class='panel panel-default'>";
            echo "<div class='panel-heading'><b>$titel</b></div>";
            echo "<div class='panel-body'>$inhoud</div></div>";
        }
        echo"</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, I will have to find a way around that then since I have more than 2 pieces of data being pulled from the database, but at least i know what the problem is now so I can find a solution to that as well, thank you

Answer (score 0):

When I inspect the element of the page, it doesn't seem to show any of the code that you have echoing out for the second column, it shows the initial `<div class='col-sm-5'></div>`.

Also, check your quotes.  I'm not sure if it will make a difference, but they are different in the second initial echo than they are in the first one for the first column.